# Smoothing linear graph

Tags: statistics

Which ways I can smooth data where are random fluctuations? This is linear graph of my data input:[image: Linear graph]

Big curves (about time 100 etc) are desirable.

I already tried sliding window. Which way do you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

The usual thing to do, is to convolve your data $f(t)$ with some window function $w_\delta(t)$ of a charactersitic width $\delta>0$, i.e.

$$\bar{f}(t) = \int_{-\infty} ^\infty dt'\, f(t')\cdot w_\delta (t',t)$$

A very popular variant is to use a gaussian window

$$w_\delta(t',t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\delta^2}}\exp\left({-\frac{(t'-t)^2}{2\delta^2}}\right).$$

**Edit**

As your data is given as discrete points, use [numerical integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration), that's also what smoothing algorithms usually do. For example if your data is given on equidistant places $t_n=t_0+n\Delta t$, you can approximate your integral as $$\int_{t_0} ^{t_N} dt' R(t')\approx \Delta t\left(\tfrac{1}{2}R(t_0)+R(t_1)+...+R(t_{N-1})+\tfrac{1}{2}R(t_N)\right)$$ using the [trapezoidal rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_Rule), replacing $R(t')$ by the integrand you need.

Comment: I forget to say. my data are discrete points. I cant derivate or integrate

Comment: @SpeedEX505 I added a remark to my answer on numerical integration, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure [moving averages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) are what you are looking for. There are a few differend kinds of them, all behave as low pass filters on your data. The example of convolution with a gaussian given by flonk is the continuous analog of moving averages in the discrete case.

Comment: I already tried moving average but it has not as good result as i expected. Maybe try to run it twice.